# Fast Fourier Transform for images

Tags: java, image-processing, filtering, fft, imagefilter

I have a problem that is associated with Fast Fourier Transform of an image. I've made an application with some filters for an images. It's a program with `JLabel`s for displaying images before and after filtration and `JButton`s for filters. So, my problem is with FFT for an image. I've seen examples for that transformation, but I really don't know how to use that in my program. I don't know how to start that.

Comment: What's your exact concern on this: how to apply a FFT to your image, how to adapt the code to your current project, how to use the FFT...?

Comment: How to adapt the code to my project. You know, i found ready to use programs, but i don't need the new program, just have to apply FFT to new JButton.

Answer (score 0):

If you have obtained the 2-D FFT code and just need to apply the function, you can read the prototype of the FFT function, i.e., the data structure of the inputs and outputs, and then prepare the data to call the function.